# Refresh a div inside a PHP file using jQuery or JavaScript and Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div displayed in the manner you see on the code and I need it to be refreshed everytime someone click on one of the links:

```
$str.= "<div id='foldersdiv'>";

  foreach ($folderslist as &$value) {
  $str.= " <a href=\"#1\" onClick=\"change_status_sp('{$spDetails->sp_id}','".$valu."');\">".$value['items']."</a>";

}
}    // loop ends

  $str.= "</div>";
```

Comment: why is this question voted down?

Comment: I thought I was doing something wrong but good luck with that. Great attitude :)

Comment: Refreshed from where? Also, don't use `onClick`, use proper event binding

Comment: refreshed from the same file list.php

Comment: @Phil I can bind it correctly once it works ...im trying to get it to load first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very basic example. This will get you started. But I'd look into the .ajax function.
It has heaps of options.

```
function change_status_sp(id)
{
    $('#foldersdiv').load('ajax/list.php?id='+id, function() {
        alert('Load was performed.');
    });
}
```

[jQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)